# array_combine combine array values in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am Using foreach loop for array.

i have two set of arrays

i want to pass these two array from one foreach loop 
code:

```
//getting variables from form
$lists=$_POST['list'];
$assigndue=$_POST['assign'];

//foreach loop
foreach (array_combine($lists,$assigndue) as $listitem => $due)
{
 $qqu="INSERT INTO `todolist`(`todoid`,`listdetail`,`assign`,`order`)VALUES('$todoidd','$listitem','$due','$o')";
        $ins=mysql_query($qqu);
}
```

every thing is working fine but i have face an issue when  array is like that >>

```
Array
(
    [0] => s
    [1] => s
    [2] => s
    [3] => a
)
```

its return this queries

```
INSERT INTO `todolist`(`todoid`,`listdetail`,`assign`,`order`)VALUES('8','s','Select Email','1') 

INSERT INTO `todolist`(`todoid`,`listdetail`,`assign`,`order`)VALUES('8','a','Select Email','2')
```

its combine the 's' in the array .

i dont know what to do next please help me to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think array_combine will just get only unique value.

Why don't you do have to combine it anyway? just `foreach` the `$lists as $index => $listitem`
and then in `foreach` loop, just add `$due = $assigndue[$index]`
It would work fine, if i understand your program logic correctly.

One more thing that it needs to be mentions is about optimization.
You should NOT have multiple query of each insert to database.
Just combine them in to single execution in following format,

`INSERT INTO todolist (COLUMNS) VALUES (ATTRIBUTE), (ATTRIBUTE)`

By making insert value clause as ARRAY and then use `join(ARRAY)` for the values clause in the query.

If you need any help in detail, please ask.

Answer (score 0):

Since `array_combine` will use the elements of the first array as keys for the resulting array and because keys have to be unique, you can't use `array_combine` if you have multiple identical elements in `$lists`.

But it should be no problem, to iterate over both arrays by yourself:

```
//getting variables from form
$lists=$_POST['list'];
$assigndue=$_POST['assign'];

//for loop
for ($i = 0; $i < count($lists) && $i < count($assigndue); $i++)
{
 $qqu="INSERT INTO `todolist`(`todoid`,`listdetail`,`assign`,`order`)VALUES('$todoidd','" . $lists[$i] . "','" . $assigndue[$i] . "','$o')";
        $ins=mysql_query($qqu);
}
```

Just make sure, that both arrays have the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Array keys must be unique, so passing s, s, s, as keys to array_combine will just give you the s and a entries

Rather than use array_combine, consider using SPLs MultipleIterator:

```
$mi = new MultipleIterator(MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ALL | MultipleIterator::MIT_KEYS_ASSOC);
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($lists), 'listitem');
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($assigndue), 'due');
foreach($mi as $details) {
    extract($details);
    $qqu = ....
}
```

Or if you're using PHP >= 5.5

```
$mi = new MultipleIterator(MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ALL | MultipleIterator::MIT_KEYS_ASSOC);
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($lists));
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($assigndue));
foreach($mi as list($listitem, $due)) {
    $qqu = ....
}
```